# Possible N plus R question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble with this question on how to solve. Can someone please help?

Mark and Juanita own a sandwich shop. They offer 3 kinds of bread, 5 kinds of meat, and 3 kinds of cheese. Each type of sandwich has a combination of exactly 3 ingredients: 1 bread, 1 meat, and 1 cheese. How many types of sandwiches are possible?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: nothing lol I dont know where to start. I asked my brother to help and he suggested this site. I believe it has to do with the N plus R equations but I only know how to do that when there are only two variables not as many as are in this questions

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple independent choices, the total number of options is the product of the number of options at each point.  If you think of three flips of a coin, you get two choices at each flip, so $2*2*2$ for all three.

Comment: Thank you! I got it figured out :)

Answer (score 0):

Applying the combinations for your exercise, first you need to focus on the different kinds of sandwiches. You have 3 of bread, 5 of meat and 3 of cheese. First you pick a bread (from the three), then you pick the meat (from the five), and then the cheese.

Then you need to apply the product rule for these selections.